# Why does SwiftUI update function doesn't work?

Tags: swiftui, state

There are 2 views (structs).

First view has a @state update:

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    @State private var lang = 0
    @State private var languages = ["English", "Spanish"]
    @State private var text1 = "Close"
    @State private var text2 = "Settings"
    @State var show = false
    @State var update = false

    var body: some View {

        ZStack{

          Button(action: {
             self.show.toggle()
          }) {
             Text("Choose language")
          }

         if self.$show.wrappedValue {

            GeometryReader {proxy in

                ChooseLanguage(show: self.$show, update: self.$update)

            }.background(Color.black.opacity(0.65)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation{
                                self.show.toggle()
                            }
            })
        }
    }.onAppear{

        switch UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "languageSettings"){
            case "en": self.lang = 0
            case "es": self.lang = 1
            default:    return
        }
        self.updateLanguage()
    }


    func updateLanguage(){

       if self.lang == 1 {

         self.text1 = "Cerrar"
         self.text2 = "Configuración"
         self.languages = ["Inglés", "Español"]
       } else {

         self.text1 = "Close"
         self.text2 = "Settings"
         self.languages = ["English", "Spanish"]
       }
    }
  }
}
```

The second view has @Binding update:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ChooseLanguage : View {

    var languages = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "langlist")

    @Binding var show: Bool
    @Binding var update: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {

                    UserDefaults.standard.set("en", forKey: "languageSettings")
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(["English", "Spanish"], forKey: "langlist")
                    self.show.toggle()
                    self.update = true
                }) {
                    Text(languages![0])
                }

                Button(action: {

                    UserDefaults.standard.set("es", forKey: "languageSettings")
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(["Inglés", "Español"], forKey: "langlist")
                    self.show.toggle()
                    self.update = true
                }) {
                    Text(languages![1])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the `func updateLanguage()` before the `.onAppear` only errors appear. 
Why I can update the values with function from the `onAppear` and I can't do this from the `wrappedValue`?

```
    if self.$update.wrappedValue {
        self.updateLanguage()
        self.update.toggle()
    }
```

This part doesn't work if to place before `}.onAppear`

Comment: By the way - use `self.update` instead of `self.$update.wrappedValue`. Much cleaner.

Comment: You set the initial values during the initalization of your view. During load up, you can not change the State again. Thats why you have a to put in the the onAppear, where the view has been loaded and the State variables can be changed

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, you can make it so much easier with using init() method for your view.

There you can declare and initialize all your @State variables with the correct value (depending on your UserDefaults)

Just to show you an example:

```
struct SetView: View {

    @State private var lang : Int
    @State private var languages : [String]
    @State private var text1 : String
    @State private var text2 : String
    @State var show = false
    @State var update = false


    init()
    {
        var state : Int = 0

        switch UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "languageSettings")
        {
            case "en": state = 0
            case "es": state = 1
            default:
                //Default value here
                state = 0
        }

        if state == 1 {
            self._lang = State(initialValue: state)
            self._text1 = State(initialValue: "Cerrar")
            self._text2 = State(initialValue: "Configuración")
            self._languages = State(initialValue: ["Inglés", "Español"])
        } else {
            self._lang = State(initialValue: state)
            self._text1 = State(initialValue: "Close")
            self._text2 = State(initialValue: "Settings")
            self._languages = State(initialValue: ["English", "Spanish"])
        }
    }
```

You won't need `onAppear` method at all, when you initialize your State variables with the correct value from the beginning.

I haven't tested it yet. Code is just out of my mind above.

Comment: 1. Need to add the types ": String, : Int"

2. " 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized "

3. Does init helps to change the value from the geometry popup view?

Comment: @Oleksandr I updated the code above.. two more questions. The program is crashing when choosing language because UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "langlist") has never been defined. You are accessing first index of that empty array. Furthermore where is self.gameLangShow declared?

Comment: Updated. **self.gameLangShow.toggle()** should be **self.show.toggle()**.
Just add this anywhere at the beginning of the struct. Should be initialized at the second view :)
**UserDefaults.standard.set(["English", "Spanish"], forKey: "langlist")**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the function after the `@State upload` value has been changed easier to send bindings for each text to the popup view.

```
GeometryReader {proxy in

                    ChooseLanguage(show: self.$show,
                                   text1: self.$text1,
                                   text2: self.$text2,
                                   languages: self.$languages)

}
```